# Modifying ServiceStack's JSON output

Tags: serialization, customization, servicestack

I have to build a REST service with ServiceStack; the responses must have a certain format. Both JSON and XML are to be supported. The standard serializers do not return the response in the format I need.
For JSON, it would be enough to wrap the result, e.g. if a function returns a list of Site objects, the JSON serializer gives me [{...}, ...], but I need {"Sites": [{...}, ...]}. The requested content-type would be "Sites+json" in this case. For other functions, "Sites" would be replaced by something else.
How can I achieve this?

Edit:
The XML has to be the direct "translation" of the JSON, like 
<Sites>...</Sites> instead of {"Sites":...}.
The standard XML serialization works differently, it always puts in the data type as well.
Has anyone an idea how to do this? I guess I have to write my own XML serializer and map all my XML types (like Sites+xml,...) to it?

Comment: Have you tried creating your DTOs around the json you need instead of trying to create a new format? It is much easier to transform your business models into highly customized DTOs then creating new formats.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that. Would it be necessary to do this for each return type, or could I use a general type and adjust the key ("Sites" etc.) somehow?
Anyway, I will have to write some custom serialization code for the XML.

Comment: if you know the resulting format, use your message DTOs as that, then map them from internal objects to the response object before returning it. Far easier to do that if you know what the result is supposed to look like.